# Grails App on Tomcat to Password Protect Files

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, single-sign-on, password-protection

I need to write a little Grails (or Java) app that will handle authentication (from our proprietary Single Sign On system) and then once authenticated allow a user to download files.  This is very straight forward if I simply include the files in the WAR file of the application, however, I'd like to avoid that since there will be multiple files and I'd rather not have to upload a new WAR file every time we add a new file.  Is it possible to accomplish this by having the application be in a WAR file but the files outside the WAR file, if so, how do I configure this kind of setup?  We'll be running this on Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Without knowing all your requirements or what you have tried and why it didn't work work for you the best I can do is give you a general idea of how to accomplish this.

Have a controller that takes an ID of the file that you want the user to download. Based on this key find the associated Domain instance. The domain should store the file name of the file. Then use this file name to resolve the file from the local file system (path configured in your application configuration). Open the file and stream the contents to the browser. Be sure to set he headers correctly to indicate the file name and size.

There are a lot of moving parts involved here but it can be done. Now, if you get stuck on something I suggest you post what you have tried and what's not working about it. Otherwise, the best we/I can do is give you general guidance/advice.

Hope this helps!

**Edit**
The real key is going to be in the controller for downloading the files. Here is a quick snippet of what that may look like:

```
  String fileName = "something.zip" // should come from your domain instance
  String filePathAndName = "/downloads/${fileName}" // should come from your configuration
  response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")
  response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=${fileName")

  // this will actually buffer/stream the file in 8k chunks instead of reading the entire file into memory.
  org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy((new File(filePathAndName)).openStream(), response.outputStream)
  response.outputStream.flush()
  response.outputStream.close()
```